# Want to subscribe API call in loop

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am writing to subscribe to an API call in a loop. But I want the next iteration of the loop to start when the data of the previous call is received.

I am writing the below code but it initiated 10 call at the instant. But I want one by one, second when first is complete.

My Code:

```
for(let i=0; i<10 ;i++){
     this.service.getData().subscribe(data=>{
          console('data received for:',i)
     });
}
```

Comment: This is a very interesting question. Will give answer in few hours, what is the optimised way to handle this.

Comment: thankyou abhay , will wait for answer

Comment: Have you tried to `repeat` operator?

Comment: I have posted the answer with a working code. Check.

Comment: It is a bit complex but solves all issues regarding polling.

Comment: just focus on the current topic, what he need is not reactive or polling but waiting the api response before go to next loop

Answer (score 1):

You can try that way , after the data is received you call the function again , it will continue till counter is smaller than 10
global variable:

```
counter = 1;

exampleFunction(){

if(this.counter < 10){
 this.service.getData().subscribe(data=>{
      if(data){
       console('data received for: counter)
       this.counter++
       this.exampleFunction()
       }  
     });
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Levin ... i tried this solution , but here is also a loop hole .... the subscribe will keep on making the calls till it do not recive the tenth answer.  .... till the 10th call is recieved it will keep on making many calls ....

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve this. It depends on your requirement. If the result of the subsequent requests depend on the response of the first, then you need to use any of the RxJS higher order mapping observables.

If not, then you could use RxJS `from` function to emit from an array of your requests and map it to emit sequentially. Try the following

```js
from(Array(10).fill(this.service.getData())).pipe(
  concatMap(request => request)
).subscribe(
  res => { },
  err => { }
);

// `Array(10).fill(this.service.getData())` produces `[this.service.getData(), this.service.getData(), ...]`
```

**Edit:** The `of` function isn't required since the request is already an observable.

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cokwtr)

Comment: @V_for_Vj: I've updated the answer. The `of` functions isn't required since the `request` was already an observable.

Answer (score 1):

**Objective :**

1. To call an Api repetitively at defined intervals(delay/gap).
2. We want to fetch the data when the previous request has finished.
3. If previous request fails, we still want to retry 2/3 time (n number of times)

**Problem with other given solutions:**

All given answers are solving the first objective. BUT NOT THE REST. In a real world scenario we don't want to burden the server (server might take 3-4 seconds to respond but we still call api at fixed interval which is **bad** ) and we also want to write defensive code on frontend ( if server fails to respond , we still want to retry).

**Solution:**

Here is the complete working code

```
    import { of, concat, Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
    import { delay, tap, skip, concatMap, map, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-comp',
      template: ` <div>{{polledApi$ | async}}</div> `,
      styleUrls: ['./comp.component.scss']
    })
    export class CompComponent implements OnInit {

      api$ = this.http.get('https://blockchain.info/ticker');

      load$ = new BehaviorSubject('');

      polledApi$: Observable<number>;

      restart$ = of('').pipe(
        delay(5000), // wait for 5sec
        tap(_ => this.load$.next('')), // calls load$
        skip(1),
      );

      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

      ngOnInit(): void {

        this.polledApi$ = this.load$.pipe(
          concatMap(_ => concat(this.api$, this.restart$)), // restart only when api gives response
          map((response: any) => response.EUR.last), // Just a map operator for this example.
          retry(3) // retry 3 times in case of error
        );
      }

    }
```

**Explanation:**

Here we have 4 Observables

1. `api$` It defines api endpoint.
2. `load$` it is a BehaviourSubject which kind of glues all observables together.
3. `restart$` used only to call `load$` after 5sec delay. it itself don't do anything.
4. polledApi$ The ACTUAL ONE which we subscribe to.

A complete explanation of all operators like concat, tap might not be possible here.
This code covers around all practical issues regarding polling.

Comment: This answer is more of a angular/Rxjs way which is extensible.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the observable into promise and wait for that:

```js
async someMethod() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     const data = await this.service.getData().toPromise();
     console.log('data received for:',i);
  }
}
```

Working example here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3tqnf6

Comment: sorry , buddy promise is not working ... doing same job as subscribe

Comment: are you sure you wrote `await`?

Comment: added stackblitz demo,

Comment: no did not write await i wrote .toPromise.then(data=>{})

Comment: appreciated if it was helpful

Comment: Converting to a promise is not a proper solution, if the code has to be reactive.

Comment: just focus on the current topic, what he need is not reactive but waiting the api response before go to next loop